# MS SQL -> ASP.NET -> JSON

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, json

Does anyone know how to convert backend data to a json response using .NET technologies? It'd be nice to have this and use jquery to call some information on the backend.

Answer (score 2):

The [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is commonly used class for serializing objects into JSON strings:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var foo = new Foo
{
    Prop1 = "value 1",
    Prop2 = 123
};

// produces: {"Prop1":"value 1","Prop2":123}
string result = serializer.Serialize(foo);
```

[Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) is another third party alternative.